# Recursive Function Compare Values in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have a table that has three columns. One is the MemberID, the other column is the score that they got, and the other one is the date when they got the score.

I want to create a result set that is going to show me a list of all the members that improved their scores overtime.

So I think that for this, a recursive table would be the answer. But I don't know how to create it.

Here is a list of my columns and some values:

```
MemberID    Score    Dates
1           3        12/31/2019
1           2        01/31/2020
1           1        02/31/2020
2           4        12/31/2019
2           6        01/31/2020
2           10       02/31/2020
3           4        12/31/2019
3           6        01/31/2020
3           5        02/31/2020
```

In this instance, my result set would only include:

MemberID 2, because it is the only member that improved over time.

Comment: What is your definition of "improving a score over time"?  Does it have to have only ever increased from the first date through to the last?  In your example, member 3's final score is higher than their initial score..

Comment: What DBMS (Oracle, MySQL, etc.) are you using? SQL is a category of languages, and any answers will need to be for your specific variant.

Comment: SQL Server, and there is no definitions regarding the scores. As long as they are higher.

Comment: Well -- should you be including MemberID 3 in your result set then?  The Feb 2020 score of 5 is higher than the 4 in Dec 2019.

Comment: Yes, MemberID 3 should also be included. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you explain why MemberID 3 should be included?

Comment: I think you'll need to narrow down your criteria a bit; do you want any MemberID who had at least one score that is higher than at least one score from a previous date? Or do you want any MemberID whose latest score is higher than their oldest score? Or a combination of those two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use analytic functions rather than recursion to solve this.

If you're looking for whether the member's latest score is higher than their earliest score, something like the following should work:

```
Select Distinct MemberID From (
  Select MemberID,
  First_Value(Score) Over (Partition by MemberID Order By Dates) First_Score,
  Last_Value(Score) Over (Partition by MemberID Order by Dates) Last_Score
From Scores
) Where Last_Score > First_Score;
```

Answer (score 0):

With `LEAD()` window function:

```
select MemberID
from (
  select MemberID, lead(score) over (partition by MemberID order by Dates) - score dif
  from tablename  
) t   
group by MemberID
having min(dif) > 0
```